# Executor Pink Slip

Tags: wills, oregon, inheritance

How much time do I have to contest that an estate executor is accurately reporting the value of the estate and distributing the assets in accordance with the will?

Jurisdiction: Oregon, US

Background: Probate Not Used

Comment: This heavily overlaps with five previous questions from MrQs. It is really getting into specific legal situations that are off topic and call for individualized legal advice from a lawyer.

Comment: Too broad, multiple questions, and specific advice. VTC and -1. ***Please** read the terms of service and the FAQ before posting further!*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it heavily overlaps with five previous questions from MrQs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant law is [ORS 113.075](https://www.oregonlaws.org/ors/113.075). You can contest the content the validity of the will or the probate itself (in Oregon, you *do* use probate). You have 4 months from "notice", which is either the general public notice in the local paper, or the mailing of the "Information to devisees" described under [ORS 113.145](https://www.oregonlaws.org/ors/113.145). If you are named in the will, the later would be applicable to you: you are to get a notice including the title of the court where the matter is pending, the decedent's name, and so on. Under [ORS 113.165](https://www.oregonlaws.org/ors/113.165), the personal representative is to file with the court an inventory of the decedent's property, within 30 days of appointment. Subsequently the PR is to file supplementary inventories when new property is discovered.